# UITextField do not post notifications

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uikit, uitextfield

If I set `textField.delegate` textField stops to post any notifications. Is this expected behavior or is this a bug? I'm targeting to iOS 7.

Comment: Share your code. Its too abstract to understand. People may close your question.

Comment: We can't read your mind, post relevant code.

Comment: the `UITextField` does not post any notification, it has never done ever. what is your question?

Comment: UITextField post UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification as expected until I define its delegate. After that it does not post notification but delegating of course works.

Comment: I think the question is completely clear and valid. I checked it, but in my case setting the delegate did not stop the delivery of UITextField notifications.

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of research I can confirm that most of the time using the delegate is not prevent posting notifications.

At this one time it did, but I can't figure out why.